# vim youcompleteme not working

Tags: macvim, plugin-you-complete-me

Currently i'm working on Node.js and I wanted some additional plugins which can help me learning this new technology. I installed tern_for_js and YouCompleteMe from Vundle. I also compiled YCM, but I don't see any auto-completion or any javascript support. Here is my .vimrc:

```
syntax on

set number
set laststatus=2
set nocompatible
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=2
set smartindent

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'ternjs/tern_for_vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
call vundle#end()

:map <F2> :echo 'Current time is ' . strftime('%c')<CR>

set guifont=ProggyCleanTT:h18
colorscheme torte
NERDTree
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong. Or did I miss something? Is there some extra configuration that have to be made?

Comment: "`0 down vote favorite I am a huge (...)"` hmmmm.... copy/paste:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875417/

Comment: That question is also asked by me..

Comment: That question was also asked by me. But i learned that i can get answer more quickly on Vim Beta community.

Comment: What was the command you used for compiling YCM?

Comment: ./install.py --tern-completer